# Custom XIB missing when loading with Swift 3 Xcode 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I am using a Storyboard with a custom XIB, everything loads up fine before the upgrade to swift 2 and xcode 7.  After the upgrade can conversion of the storyboard to xcode 8.  My viewcontroller displays the view but its missing my custom XIB.  Looking at the storyboard file, it looks like there is a bug with the conversion of a storyboard with custom XIB.  Anyone else having this issue?

```
required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: self.dynamicTypeName, bundle: bundle)
    let nibView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    self.mainView = nibView
    self.mainView.frame = bounds
    self.mainView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    self.addSubview(mainView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong with the layout process with swift 3, because before the upgrade

calling self.mainView.frame = bounds, would give you the correct bounds, but now with swift 3 its always (0, 0, 1000, 1000), so I had to set the frame in layoutSubviews to get the correct bounds.

```
open override func layoutSubviews() {
    self.mainView.frame = bounds
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, Did you find any solution.

Comment: yes, try setting the your custom xib frame in layoutSubviews

Comment: Not sure why it is not taking the frame automatically, though the room provided is still full screen (say mainscreen.rect)